# AWS Elastic Beanstalk status severe but no causes and working well

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, apollo

I have a nodejs apollo server (graphql) and almost all the time the status is severe, but the server is working well. Also, there is no cause information about it.

I have checked all the logs and could not find the reason, anyone has an idea what could be?

access.log

```
IP - - [22/Dec/2020:09:08:53 +0000] "GET /api/subscriptions HTTP/1.1" 101 27 "-" "-" "IP"
IP - - [22/Dec/2020:09:08:53 +0000] "POST /api/graphql HTTP/1.1" 200 163 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "172.31.37.93, IP"
IP - - [22/Dec/2020:09:08:53 +0000] "POST /api/graphql HTTP/1.1" 200 187 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "172.31.37.93, IP"
IP - - [22/Dec/2020:09:08:53 +0000] "POST /api/graphql HTTP/1.1" 200 187 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "172.31.37.93, IP"
IP - - [22/Dec/2020:09:08:53 +0000] "POST /api/graphql HTTP/1.1" 200 163 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "172.31.37.93, IP"
IP - - [22/Dec/2020:09:08:54 +0000] "GET /api/subscriptions HTTP/1.1" 101 27 "-" "-" "IP"
IP - - [22/Dec/2020:09:08:54 +0000] "GET /api/subscriptions HTTP/1.1" 101 27 "-" "-" "IP"
IP - - [22/Dec/2020:09:08:54 +0000] "GET /api/subscriptions HTTP/1.1" 101 27 "-" "-" "IP"
IP - - [22/Dec/2020:09:08:54 +0000] "GET /api/subscriptions HTTP/1.1" 101 27 "-" "-" "IP"
IP - - [22/Dec/2020:09:08:54 +0000] "GET /api/subscriptions HTTP/1.1" 101 27 "-" "-" "IP"
IP - - [22/Dec/2020:09:08:54 +0000] "GET /api/subscriptions HTTP/1.1" 101 27 "-" "-" "IP"
```

the health overview pt1:
[image]

the health overview pt2:
[image]

the monitor of the health:
[image]

Comment: Following the guidelines of StackOverflow, code or logs should be provided in text format, not images. Can you refer to the guide below and correct it?
[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  /  [do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @myeongkilkim I think it more applies to the case when original code or logs are supplied in textual forms and someone makes screenshot of that. It is not much use to have web UI copied to text format. It would require a lot of formatting and not really helps understanding the problem. I voted this question to look OK

Comment: @Yegor Androsov Thanks for the good comment. I agree that moving the non-text web UI into text is useless. However, the exact part I intended is to delete unnecessary images such as the first picture (Health red-! severe). In addition, in the case of health error within aws, user can obtain return status and log. This is what I wrote because, as I said in the reference link I commented at the beginning, I thought it would be more appropriate to paste it in text form for search.

Comment: @myeongkilkim I did upload the first picture because usually the causes btn is enable when there is a problem with the health. Some people might ask me to click on btn "causes" so thats why I embedded the picture.

Comment: @Guilherme Ramos I understand what the first image means. thx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Could be a linked service such as amazon SNS that has messages in its dead-letter queue. Or a failed deployment. Or something else.. Have you already tried rebuilding the app? AWS EB indeed is sometimes difficult to debug.